# How to describe an outfit

Tags: word-usage

If I want to say that my outfit consists of three pieces of clothing (for example: a skirt, a t-shirt, and a jacket) can I say that my outfit has three garments? Does it give the same meaning? Or it doesn't make sense?

Comment: a men's [three piece suit](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=three+piece+suit&biw=1242&bih=580&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCsc7vhanSAhVmD8AKHXZ8CWMQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=%22three+piece+suit%22) consists of trousers, jacket and a waistcoat (gilet/vest)  It's called a suit because the three different garments are made from the same cloth (material). But it would never include a shirt, that is sold separately... well 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mari-Lou suggested, this is actually a two-piece outfit, because the T-shirt wouldn't count.

If the skirt and jacket truly match, it's a two-piece outfit.  Otherwise, you're creating your own ensemble, *pairing* a skirt and jacket.

In practice, people wouldn't tend to describe this outfit as a two-piece outfit.  If the cloth is exactly the same, then you would say "suit."  Otherwise, you would say "skirt and jacket."

I know these things from reading fashion magazines occasionally in waiting rooms.